# HTC one X storage issues

Tags: storage, htc

i just got an HTC one X 32gb (i know its old), but "app storage" is only 6.76 gb and "phone storage" is 25.24gb,
I cant downloade more apps beacaus "app storage" is full but i have 18 gb free under "phone storage"im using this phone for games like tetris and doodle jump so games is all i will have on it, 
How do i change download location or merge the partitions so i can doenload more apps without deleting old ones?